# Getting SIGABRT error with simple storyboard app

Tags: ios, uitableview, sigabrt, uncaught-exception

I have a problem that I've searched the internet for a solution for with no avail.  I'm following along in chapter 10 of Apress' Beginning iOS 5 development which is on storyboards.

I'm thinking the book is missing a simple piece of code and since I'm going through this for the first time, I don't know how to resolve it.

I've restarted the project twice, but keep getting this error in the debugger:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

```
#import "BIDTaskListController.h"

@interface BIDTaskListController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *tasks;
@end

@implementation BIDTaskListController

@synthesize tasks;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tasks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"Walk the dog",
                  @"URGENT:Buy milk",
                  @"Clean hidden lair",
                  @"Invent miniature dolphins",
                  @"Find new henchmen",
                  @"Get revenge on do-gooder heroes",
                  @"URGENT: Fold laundry",
                  @"Hold entire world hostage",
                  @"Manicure",
                  nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;

    self.tasks = nil;
}
```

//

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [tasks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *identifier = nil;
    NSString *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSRange urgentRange = [task rangeOfString:@"URGENT"];
    if (urgentRange.location == NSNotFound) {
        identifier = @"plainCell";
    } else {
        identifier = @"attentionCell";
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    cellLabel.text = task;

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Comment: you need to add UITableViewDataSource in your interface file

Comment: Added it as a protocol in my implementation and header file like so:     @interface BIDTaskListController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDataSource>         This didn't work...I also have my app delegate.h and.m; bidviewcontroller.h and .m; Should I add anything to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lack of code:

...

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.tag = 1;
    [cell addSubview:label];
}

UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
cellLabel.text = task;
```

....

Comment: Awesome! That brought up the table view. One minor thing though: I have a table view set up with two view cells, each containing they're own labels. One label is for just the URGENT responses which should appear red. When I run the app, they appear just like the other data.  I have the text color set to red and the view tag set to 1.  Any ideas?

Comment: [cell addSubview:label];                                           then add code :                                                      if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"attentionCell"])
            label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

Comment: I can't say thanks enough! Surprised the book had that much code out of it.  Everything is running smoothly now!  Mad props!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think that your original problem isn't anything missing from the code, it's missing from your storyboard configuration! IIRC, the book describes creating two cell prototypes in the storyboard: One with red text and its identifier set to "attentionCell", and one with black text and its identifier set to "plainCell". If those two cells exist within the tableview in the storyboard, with the right identifiers set, then the original piece of code you posted should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no missing code. I followed the instructions in Chapter 10 exactly, and it compiled and ran fine.
The top of page 363 explains that a table view loaded from a storyboard can create cells on demand, and there is no need to check for a nil return.